# how do i get value which returns from service (WCF) using JQuery?

Tags: jquery, wcf

**client:**

```
 $("#btn").click(function (event) {
                $.getJSON('http://host/myservice.svc/GetCount?method=?', { Id: '2' }, function (customer) {

                   //how to get an value ??? here ????                    
                });
                //return false;
            });
```

**Server**

```
public long GetCount(string method, string Id)
{ 
  return 100;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have jsonP endpoint which automatically converts and sends the jsonp object to the user.
if jsonP you should get straightway.

If it is not jsonp end point , change your backend to a well formated string which is of jsonP notation and do a eval at the UI.

You will have some cross browsers issues also.follow the below link

```
http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/107136.aspx
```

Custom jsonp binding

```
<endpoint address="ajax" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="jsonpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="JsonBehavior" contract="InterfaceGoeshere"/>
```

Comment: do you have to define attribues at the interface level for returning .json?

Comment: @chicagoland , without doing any changes what value you are getting in customer , alert(customer) and see what it is returning.

Comment: @chicagoland , do onething go step by step , first just call the wcf by just normal ajax call instead of getJSON , you need to do lot of things to get jsonp working. Right now use regular ajax and call the wcf and see what result you are getting.

Comment: if i do `alert(customer)` i get the message undefined

Comment: you mean regular ajax `$.ajax(...)` ?

Comment: yes , your code is not rgiht from UI and from backed to use getJsonp. so use regular ajax and see if you can print the customer...object

Comment: see this example also , he explained to get end to end with jsonp padding http://jasonkelly.net/2009/05/using-jquery-jsonp-for-cross-domain-ajax-with-wcf-services/

Comment: i double check that and i am using custom jsonp binding